# System Status: Notice 5.1.0 After Upgrade

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

Need a bit of help just upgraded to the latest version 5.1.0 however now when I click in on the "System Status: Notice" link in the bottom footer I get an error.

Can anyone help me fix this, please?

Error calling get API for UFGroup (aka Profiles)Array ( [error_code] => no such field [sql] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`, a.title as `title`, a.frontend_title as `frontend_title`, a.description as `description`, a.help_pre as `help_pre`, a.help_post as `help_post`, a.limit_listings_group_id as `limit_listings_group_id`, a.post_URL as `post_URL`, a.add_to_group_id as `add_to_group_id`, a.add_captcha as `add_captcha`, a.is_map as `is_map`, a.is_edit_link as `is_edit_link`, a.is_uf_link as `is_uf_link`, a.is_update_dupe as `is_update_dupe`, a.cancel_URL as `cancel_URL`, a.is_cms_user as `is_cms_user`, a.notify as `notify`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.name as `name`, a.created_id as `created_id`, a.created_date as `created_date`, a.is_proximity_search as `is_proximity_search`, a.cancel_button_text as `cancel_button_text`, a.submit_button_text as `submit_button_text` FROM civicrm_uf_group a WHERE (a.is_active = "1") LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in 'field list'] [tip] => add debug=1 to your API call to have more info about the error [is_error] => 1 [error_message] => DB Error: no such field [debug_information] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`, a.title as `title`, a.frontend_title as `frontend_title`, a.description as `description`, a.help_pre as `help_pre`, a.help_post as `help_post`, a.limit_listings_group_id as `limit_listings_group_id`, a.post_URL as `post_URL`, a.add_to_group_id as `add_to_group_id`, a.add_captcha as `add_captcha`, a.is_map as `is_map`, a.is_edit_link as `is_edit_link`, a.is_uf_link as `is_uf_link`, a.is_update_dupe as `is_update_dupe`, a.cancel_URL as `cancel_URL`, a.is_cms_user as `is_cms_user`, a.notify as `notify`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.name as `name`, a.created_id as `created_id`, a.created_date as `created_date`, a.is_proximity_search as `is_proximity_search`, a.cancel_button_text as `cancel_button_text`, a.submit_button_text as `submit_button_text` FROM civicrm_uf_group a WHERE (a.is_active = "1") LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in 'field list'] )

Answer (score 4):

SOOOO, I am a total idiot forgot to run the upgrade URL.... yep so that happened.

Sorry all

Comment: as in visiting the /civicrm/upgrade and actually running the database upgrade after updating the codebase in case anyone stumbles on this